# Unable to build from Singularity: while parsing definition:

Tags: docker, artificial-intelligence, singularity-container

I am trying to build a singularity via the below link,
`wget https://bitbucket.org/ipc2018-classical/team1/raw/ipc-2018-seq-sat/Singularity`

with the below command

```
 sudo singularity build planner.img Singularity
```

But, I am getting the error as:

```
FATAL:   Unable to build from Singularity: while parsing definition: Singularity: failed to parse deffile header: header key <!DOCTYPE html> had no val.
```

I am using singularity version:  3.5.1.

Does anyone happen to know what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `wget` didn't go as expected and wrote out an html doc rather than the definition file. Double check that the content of the downloaded `Singularity` file is what you expect it to be.